# Return list of integer values next string values

Tags: vba, excel

I have two columns of data.  The first column is a list of unique integer values.  The second column is a list of string values of which some of the values duplicate.  I want to write a brief macro (or cell formula) that will return the integer value next to the string.

```
Integers   Strings    Ideal Printout
   0         Bob           0
   1         Joe           1,2
   2         Joe           1,2 
   3         Susan         3,5  
   4         Sally         4
   5         Susan         3,5
```

Sorry if the above is not clear.  Having a hard time articulating this.  I am also happy if the printout is a column for each integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Public Function GETMATCHES(ByVal match As String, ByVal cells As Range, ByVal columnOffset As Integer) As String
    Dim result As String
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In cells
        If cell.Value2 = match Then
            result = result & "," & cell.Offset(0, columnOffset).Value2
        End If
    Next
    If Len(result) > 0 Then
        result = Right(result, Len(result) - 1)
    End If
    GETMATCHES = result
End Function
```

I used it like this:

```
=GETMATCHES(B2,$B$2:$B$7,-1)
```

Comment: You sir are my hero.  Thanks!